# Scope of Javascript Variable in Knockout $root and $parent

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, typescript

I have a javascript viewmodel that is set up to use knockout and I have two viewmodels within that viewmodel that I have databindings on in the context of my page. 
So I have my page set up so that one viewmodel is bound to a section of my page with a "with" binding and then another viewmodel is bound to another section with a "with" binding. 
Right now I have it set up so that for one item on the page after a click event I'm bound to the $root (the container viewmodel) and I want to edit some observables on the other viewmodel (not in this section of the page that I have the "with" binding). In the method on "root" that I call I set it up so that "var self = this" and then edit the properties I need to edit on the other viewmodel. The problem is that I have is that the scope of the method is changed when I call $root or $parent within the "with" binding from being the original object I wanted to manipulate (the container or "root" in this instance) to being the viewmodel that had the "with" binding on it, so it doesn't have any of the variables I need or the other viewmodel I need to manipulate.

Is there a way to change my scope from within a $parent or $root call to something other than what I am getting currently? I just want the scope to be that of the container object and not the particular viewmodel.

Code Example (in TypeScript):

```
class Container
{
  viewModelA = new ViewModel();
  viewModelB = new ViewModelB();

  clickMe(){
    var self = this;
    console.log(self);
    self.viewModelB.property("yes");
  }
}

<span data-bind="with: viewModelA"> <button data-bind="event: {click: $root.clickMe}" /></span>
```

The console.log will output viewModelA and I'll get an error on that self.viewModelB call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to change the scope of a `click` handler.

### Using `Bind`

You can use the `bind` [javascript method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), with that you can explicitly specify what should be the `this` value when your function gets called:

```
<button data-bind="event: { click: $root.clickMe.bind($root) }" />
```

And in your `clickMe` the `this` will be your `Container`

### Pass `$root` as a parameter

```
<button data-bind="event: { click: function() { $root.clickMe($root) } }" />
```

And you need to change your `clickMe` to:

```
clickMe(container){
    var self = container;
    console.log(self);
    self.viewModelB.property("yes");
  }
```

### Use an "arrow function"

Or you can change your `clickMe` to an "arrow function" this is a TypeScript construct to preserve `this` during function invocation:

```
clickMe = () => {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self);
    self.viewModelB.property("yes");
  }
```

However this moves the `clickMe` from the `Container` prototype into an instance function so it may have performance issues but you don't need to change your databinding experessions.

SideNote: Knockout has a dedicated [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) so you can replace `data-bind="event: {click: $root.clickMe}"` with `data-bind="click: $root.clickMe"`.